# How to solve 'could not find method implemtatation()' error?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on an AndroidStudio Project, and I can't sync the project with de gradle. I have the following error :

```html
ERROR: Could not find method implemtatation() for arguments [project ':mapwize'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I tried to change the gradle version but it didn't work.

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution, seems like you mistyped the word `implemtatation` it should be `implementation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `build.gradle` in your modules (not the top level file).
There is a typo in the `dependencies` block.

You are using `implemtatation` instead of `implementation`